# tar/bz2 compress a file removing uncompressed original

Tags: linux, compression, tar, bzip2

Is there any way to turn a directory called dir1 into dir1.tar.bz2 without keeping the original?  I need to save space and want to compress some large files but don't have enough room to keep a compressed copy and the original.  Is there any way to transform the existing file into an archive directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tar` can't do that, but you can achieve what you want with:

`find dir1 -depth -print0 | xargs -0 tar --create --no-recursion --remove-file --file - | bzip2 > dir1.tar.bz2`

where:

- `find dir1 -depth -print0`

  lists all files and directories in `dir1`, listing the directory contents before the directory itself (`-depth`). The use of `-print0` (and `-0` in `xargs` below) is the key to **supporting directory and file names with embedded spaces**.
- `xargs -0 tar --create --no-recursion --remove-file --file -`

  creates a tar archive and adds every file or directory to it. The tar archive is sent to standard output with option `--file -`.
- `bzip2 > dir1.tar.bz2`

  compresses the tar archive from standard input to a file called `dir1.tar.bz2`.

**The amount of free disk space needed is the size of the largest compressed file in `dir1`** because `tar`, when processing a file, waits until archiving is complete before deleting it. Since `tar` is piped to `bzip2`, for a short moment, before `tar` removes it, every file resides in two places: uncompressed in the filesystem and compressed inside `dir1.tar.bz2`.

I was curious to see how disk space was used so I made this experiment on my Ubuntu VM:

1. Create a 1 GB filesystem:

   ```
   $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/1gb bs=1M count=1024
   $ losetup /dev/loop0 /tmp/1gb
   $ mkfs.ext3 /dev/loop0
   $ sudo mount /dev/loop0 /tmp/mnt
   $ df -h
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/loop0     1008M   34M  924M   4% /tmp/mnt
   ```
2. Fill the filesystem with 900 1 megabyte-files:

   ```
   $ chown jaume /tmp/mnt
   $ mkdir /tmp/mnt/dir1
   $ for (( i=0; i<900; i++ )); do dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/mnt/dir1/file$i bs=1M count=1; done
   $ chown -R jaume /tmp/mnt
   $ df -h
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/loop0     1008M  937M   20M  98% /tmp/mnt
   ```

   The filesystem is now 98% full.
3. Make a copy of `dir1` for later verification:

   ```
   $ cp -a /tmp/mnt/dir1 /tmp/dir1-check
   ```
4. Compress `dir1`:

   ```
   $ ls /tmp/mnt
   dir1  lost+found
   $ find /tmp/mnt/dir1 -depth -print0 | xargs -0 tar --create --no-recursion --remove-file --file - | bzip2 > /tmp/mnt/dir1.tar.bz2
   $
   ```

   **Note that the commands ran without any 'no space left on device' errors.**

   `dir1` was removed, only `dir1.tar.bz2` exists:

   ```
   $ ls /tmp/mnt
   dir1.tar.bz2  lost+found
   ```
5. Expand `dir1.tar.bz2` and compare to `/tmp/dir1-check`:

   ```
   $ tar --extract --file dir1.tar.bz2 --bzip2 --directory /tmp
   $ diff -s /tmp/dir1 /tmp/dir1-check
   (...)
   Files /tmp/dir1/file97 and /tmp/dir1-check/file97 are identical
   Files /tmp/dir1/file98 and /tmp/dir1-check/file98 are identical
   Files /tmp/dir1/file99 and /tmp/dir1-check/file99 are identical
   $
   ```

   Copy of `dir1` and uncompressed `dir1.tar.bz2` are identical!

This can be generalized in a script:

1. Create a file called `tarrm` (or any other name of your liking) with these contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
   # This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License for more details.
   # You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

   # dir is first argument
   dir="$1"
   # check dir exists
   if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
       echo "$(basename $0): error: '$dir' doesn't exist" 1>&2
       exit 1
   fi
   # check if tar file exists
   if [ -f "${dir}.tar" -o -f "${dir}.tar.bz2" ]; then
       echo "$(basename $0): error: '$dir.tar' or '${dir}.tar.bz2' already exist" 1>&2
       exit 1
   fi

   # --keep is second argument
   if [ "X$2" == "X--keep" ]; then
       # keep mode
       removefile=""
       echo " Tarring '$dir'"
   else
       removefile="--remove-file"
       echo " Tarring and **deleting** '$dir'"
   fi

   # normalize directory name (for example, /home/jaume//// is a legal directory name, but will break ${dir}.tar.bz2 - it needs to be converted to /home/jaume)
   dir=$(dirname "$dir")/$(basename "$dir")

   # create compressed tar archive and delete files after adding them to it
   find "$dir" -depth -print0 | xargs -0 tar --create --no-recursion $removefile --file - | bzip2 > "${dir}.tar.bz2"

   # return status of last executed command
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
       echo "$(basename $0): error while creating '${dir}.tar.bz2'" 1>&2
   fi
   ```
2. Make it executable:

   `chmod a+x tarrm`

The script does some basic error checking: `dir1` must exist, `dir1.tar.bz2` and `dir1.tar` shouldn't exist and has a *keep* mode. It also supports directory and file names with embedded spaces.

**I've tested the script but can't guarantee it is flawless**, so first use it in keep mode:

`./tarrm dir1 --keep`

This invocation will add `dir1` to `dir1.tar.bz2` but won't delete the directory.

When you trust the script use it like this:

`./tarrm dir1`

The script will inform you that `dir1` will be deleted in the process of tarring it:

`Tarring and **deleting** 'dir1'`

For example:

```
$ ls -lF
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 jaume jaume 4096 2013-10-11 11:00 dir 1/
$ find "dir 1"
dir 1
dir 1/subdir 1
dir 1/subdir 1/file 1
dir 1/file 1
$ /tmp/tarrm dir\ 1/
 Tarring and **deleting** 'dir 1/'
$ echo $?
0
$ ls -lF
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jaume jaume 181 2013-10-11 11:00 dir 1.tar.bz2
$ tar --list --file dir\ 1.tar.bz2 
dir 1/subdir 1/file 1
dir 1/subdir 1/
dir 1/file 1
dir 1/
```

Comment: Interesting approach. It does seem to depend on there being enough disk space to hold both the uncompressed tar archive as well as the almost-fully-compressed archive, though, since bzip2 (as well as other tools that I'm aware of) don't actually compress *in place*. Maybe, just maybe, you could use a pipe from a subshell to help with that?

Comment: Yes, my proposed solution does indeed need enough space to compress `dir1.tar`. Another (much simpler) approach would be to use `zip` instead: `zip --recurse-paths --move "dir 1.zip" "dir 1"`. I've edited my answer to mention `zip`...

Comment: Well, as it turns out `zip` is not an option. I rolled back to the original answer. `zip` doesn't provide what the OP wants (from the man page): *--move Move the specified files into the zip archive; actually, this deletes the target directories/files **after making** the specified zip archive. If a directory becomes empty after removal of the files, the directory is also removed. **No deletions are done until zip has created the archive without error.***

Comment: Impressive solution.  I guess the remaining question is how much free space is required to run this operation.  Does it require original file + archive, or is it less than that?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks for the hint, I noticed I could use `tar --create` instead of `tar --append` so I improved the solution to pipe and send the compressed output to a file. Now the amount of free disk space needed is the compressed size of the file in `dir1` that is the largest after being compressed, much less than `dir.tar`.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal I've improved the solution and now the amount of free disk space needed is the compressed size of the file in `dir1` that is the largest after being compressed. I made a test with a filesystem 98% full and worked without a hitch.

Comment: I haven't tested it myself yet, but am awarding you the answer on the amount of time and effort you put in.  You should put this script into a higher level language like Python and opensource it.  Thanks for your work!

Comment: I appreciate your comments very much, Gregg. My Python (and PHP, Perl, etc for that matter) is pretty bad so I don't think I'll rewrite the script but I've added the standard GPL copying permission statement. Make sure you have a backup of your data before testing the script.

Comment: I'd upvote this again if I could, but alas, I've already used my allotment of upvotes on this particular answer...

Comment: I think something may be missing here. the variable "removedir" isn't used, and when tested, this program delete files only but not directories. I'll just add `if [ "$removedir" == "true" ]; then;rm -rf $dir; fi`

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing it out and for your suggestion. I'll check the script later and edit it.

Comment: @Kwaio In my tests I found out that the `removedir` variable is not necessary, so I've removed it. The directory is deleted if `--keep` is not specified, I wonder why it only deleted files in your test. I ran `tarrm` on OS X 10.9.1.

Comment: I'm using RHEL3 with kernel 2.4.17 and coreutils 4.5.3. that may change things. Thanks for the script anyway files are what takes the most space.